# Android - search tool bar in MapActivity

Tags: android, android-layout

I need a search toolbar on Google Map.

I display the map with the use of MapActivity. 
The way I did is via the create project wizard, when you a create a new project, you can choose from basic activity, empty activity, map activity. 

I selected MapActivity. 
In XML file I had only this:

```
<resources> 
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve"
         translatable="false">AIzaSyCx3iR5fkeWr2LUf6JBHwGLEEkeghL3snk
    </string> 
</resources>
```

So what is the way to insert that search toolbar on the map?

Then how to add that search tool bar. If I add a layout then an error it is shown.

Comment: Please be more explicit about what you want to achieve and the ways you tried because I have no idea what is "here" and also what "fields" you use.

Comment: I need a search toolbar on google map. I display the map with the use of MapActivity(When you a create a new project, it ask basic activity, empty activity, map activity. I selected MapActivity. In xml file ihad only this: 
<resources>    
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">AIzaSyCx3iR5fkeWr2LUf6JBHwGLEEkeghL3snk</string>
</resources>   Then how to add that search tool bar. If i add layout it shows error

Comment: Add this to your question please.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is the following:
I would have an activity which has a fragment that contain the map inside.

Inside the activity I would have a method that display the fragment with the map:

```
 public void showMap() {

    MapLocationFragment locationFragment = MapLocationFragment.newInstance();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, locationFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}

activity xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <include
      android:id="@+id/app_bar_include"
      layout="@layout/app_bar_layout_device" />

   <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Now, inside the MapLocationFragment you need to have something like that:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maps_layout, container, false);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    initializeMapIfNeeded();
}

private void initializeMapIfNeeded() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        loadMapAsync();
    }
}

private void loadMapAsync() {
    ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMapAsync(getOnMapReadyCallback());
}

public OnMapReadyCallback getOnMapReadyCallback() {
    return new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
            googleMap = map;
            if (googleMap == null) {
                return;
            }

            googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(getMapMpOnMyLocationClickListener());
            googleMap.setLocationSource(getNewLocationSource());
            googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(getCameraChangeListener());
            //do other stuff too
        }
    };
}

xml:

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/location_map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_set_as"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For more details look at this project:

[Sunshine app](https://github.com/toaderandrei/sunshine-udacity-master)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it.

`public class MapsActivity extends FragementActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,LocationListener` in here, Put the AppCompatActivity instead of   the FragementActivity.